# Has Han Solo ever been Force-Sensitive/a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, han-solo

In the Star Wars comic Infinities: The Empire Strikes Back, Luke Skywalker dies on Hoth, but not before telling Han to go to Dagobah and become a Jedi.  Han takes his dead friend's word to heart and travels there, but when he arrives it is Leia who Yoda chooses to train, not Han.

This got me thinking - has there ever been a universe, a mention, anything that ever hinted or implied that Han could be Force-Sensitive or a Jedi?

Comment: Han is usually held up as the opposite of Force-sensitive.

Comment: Per the (non-canon) Star Wars: Graphics - https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7770881d76d60323a07bb11dee918cb8

Comment: Why would he have been? He is able to (clumsily) wield Luke's lightsaber, and if I'm not mistaken all things have midichlorians, but that's no basis for him being Force sensitive